# Передвинуть мышь Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, minecraft

Делаю бота на Python для игры Minecraft.
Двигать персонажа научился, правда пришлось повозиться с этим, так как оказалось что Minecraft блокирует имитацию клавиатуры, так что pyautogui не работал. Сделал с помощью ctypes. Но как сделать с мышью? Pyautogui не работает.